What is a [or the proper] make directive to substitute a "/" with a "\" in a makefile path?
I'm trying to write a makefile that will accomidate both a Windows or a Linux based build.
The "/" vs "" is getting in my way. I'm trying to do a character substitution in the makefile to no success. I thought this would work, but no.
PATH=OFC\obj\bin
WINPATH=$(patsubst,/,\\,$(PATH))

WINPATH doesn't get set. It's blank. This has to be a fairly common thing that's done.  How do you do it?

Tip: you should never use the variable PATH in your makefile, unless you're trying to actually change the path used to look up programs used by the recipes in your makefile.

s/use/set/ in my comment above (took too long to notice the poor wording choice)

You have a number of errors in your makefile.
First, the substitution is backwards:
PATH = OFC\obj\bin
WINPATH = $(patsubst,/,\\,$(PATH))

You have backslashes in PATH, but you're substituting FROM forward slashes TO backslashes, so this won't change any backslashes.
Second, your invocation of the patsubst function is wrong in two ways: first, you should have a space, not a comma, between the function name and the first argument.  Second, patsubst substitutes PATTERNS and you don't have any here (patterns contain %).  patsubst only substitutes one group per word.
You want to use the subst function to substitute every instance of the group in every word.  This will work:
PATH = OFC\obj\bin
WINPATH = $(subst \,/,$(PATH))

But, I think it's backwards since I assume PATH should be UNIX paths and WINPATH should be windows paths.

Finally got it to work....
/ := $(if $(filter Windows_NT, $(OS)),\,/)
BINPATH=OFC$/obj$/bin

OFC\obj\bin
Hat tip to Mark Galeck. I saw his post on the subject.

But.... this doesn't do anything like what the question asked for, which is replace slashes/backslashes in existing variables.

I sure I asked the question incorrectly. I didn't know enough at the time to ask the right question.
